# Cohomology Ring Torus

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I want to prove that the graded homology ring with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients of $S^1 \times S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta]/(\alpha^2, \beta^2)$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in degree 1.

*My attempt*:

Let's consinder the projections $\pi_1, \pi_2: S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$. They induce ring homomorphisms $$\pi_1^*,\pi_2^*:H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^2) \to H^*(S^1 \times S^1; \mathbb{Z}).$$ Analogously, the inclusions $\iota_1, \iota_2: S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ induce ring homomorphisms $$\iota_1^*,\iota_2^*: H^*(S^1 \times S^1; \mathbb{Z})\to H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^2).$$

As $\pi_i \circ \iota_i = Id$, we have that $\iota_i^* \circ \pi_i^* = Id$. So $$\langle \iota_1^*, \iota_2^* \rangle: H^*(S^1 \times S^1; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^*(S^1; \mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(S^1; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^2) \otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/(\beta^2)$$ has a section, which means that it is surjective. Maybe with Kunneth we can show that it must be injective as well. Then, I need to prove that 
$$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^2) \otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/(\beta^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta](\alpha^2, \beta^2)$$

Any hint?

Comment: You want a tensor product there, not a product. The reason is that your "section" is not a ring map if you define it on the product instead of the tensor product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Kunneth theorem $H^*(S^1 \times S^1) \cong H^*(S^1) \otimes H^*(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha^2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/\beta^2$.

**The tensor product is to be intended as tensor product of graded $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras.**

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha^2 \cong \mathbb{Z} \cdot \{1, \alpha\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\beta]/\beta^2 \cong \mathbb{Z} \cdot \{1, \beta\}$ as graded $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (with gradings 0, 1), hence $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha^2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/\beta^2 \cong \mathbb{Z} \cdot \{1, \alpha \otimes 1, 1 \otimes \beta, \alpha \otimes \beta\}$ as graded $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (with gradings 0, 1, 1, 2).

At the same time it holds that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha\, \beta]/(\alpha^2, \beta^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \cdot \{1, \alpha, \beta, \alpha\beta\}$ as graded $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (with gradings 0, 1, 1, 2).

Hence they **are** isomorphic as *graded $\mathbb{Z}$-modules*, but the isomorphism **is not** a isomorphism of *graded $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras*.

In fact $(1 \otimes \beta)\cdot(\alpha\otimes 1) = (-1)^{|\beta||\alpha|} \alpha \otimes \beta = - \alpha \otimes \beta \neq \alpha \otimes \beta$ while $\beta \cdot \alpha = \beta\alpha = \alpha\beta$.

In general, there could not be an isomorphism of graded $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras between $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha^2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/\beta^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha\, \beta]/(\alpha^2, \beta^2)$ because the first one is graded-commutative with terms of odd degrees, while the second one is commutative.

Comment: Can you explain why $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^2)\otimes \mathbb{Z}[\beta]/(\beta^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta]/(\alpha^2, \beta^2)$?

Comment: Well you should take the tensor product of graded commutative algebras. The Künneth theorem holds in this generality, so your answer is slightly misleading.

Comment: @Pedro I wrote «the tensor product is to be intended as tensor product of graded Z-algebras»: isn't it the same thing you're saying? I mean, I think that the tensor product of «graded-commutative algebras» and the tensor product of «graded algebras» are the same thing. Am I wrong?

Comment: The thing is that here the grading is homological, so as you observe the definition of the tensor product has to take into account the homological grading. The definition is thus that $(x\otimes y)(x'\otimes y') = (-1)^{|x'||y|} xx'\otimes yy'$ on homogeneous elements. This fixes the issue you claim exists in the Künneth isomorphism, which does not exist in reality. You even use this rule, but then for some reason claim that $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ in $H^*(T^2)$ which is not true: cohomology rings are graded-commutative.

Comment: @Pedro I do not claim that $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ holds in $H^*(T^2)$ but I claim that it holds in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]/(\alpha^2, \beta^2)$, which was the cohomology ring proposed by the OP, which is in fact not graded-commutative.

Comment: @CNS709 Fair enough. Perhaps what one should tell the OP is that that ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[a,b]$ as a (free!) graded ring on generators $a,b$ of degree $1$, since there automatically $a^2=b^2=0$ by degree reasons, and $ab=-ba$ by construction. :)

Comment: @Pedro Why must $a^2=0$ for general "degree reasons"? In particular for the torus, I don't see why $a^2=0$ holds. As far as I understand it, $a$ being of degree one just means $a$ lives in the first grading of the graded ring; it does not mean $a$ has order $2$

Comment: @FShrike If $|a|=1$ then $a^2= aa = (-1)^{|a||a|}aa = -a^2$.

Comment: @Pedro Ah. I haven't got to that part of Hatcher yet ; )